# Python selenium webserver status code

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Как можно получить статус код от страницы (например: 200), если заходишь через selenium?

Answer (score 1):

Ванильный selenium такого не умеет<sup>1</sup>.

Используй библиотеку [`selenium-wire`](https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/). Это враппер вокруг `selenium`, который добавляет в `webdriver` вещи, которые не имплементированы в оригинальной библиотеке. Например, драйвер сохраняет все запросы и ответы, доступные через `webdriver.requests`:

```
import contextlib
from seleniumwire import webdriver 


with contextlib.closing(webdriver.Chrome()) as driver:
    driver.get('https://ru.stackoverflow.com')
    for request in driver.requests:
        if request.response:
            print(request.response.status_code, request.path)
```

Код выдаст:

```
200 https://accounts.google.com/ListAccounts?gpsia=1&source=ChromiumBrowser&json=standard
200 https://www.gstatic.com/chrome/intelligence/assist/ranker/models/translate/2017/03/translate_ranker_model_20170329.pb.bin
200 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/
200 https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js
200 https://cdn.sstatic.net/Shared/stacks.css?v=baa63b2b0ac4
200 https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/hero/anonymousHeroQuestions.svg?v=748bfb046b78
200 https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/hero/anonymousHeroAnswers.svg?v=d5348b00eddc
200 https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.ru.js?v=5400b0aeda77
200 https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/ru/primary.css?v=782a2b625d22
200 https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/hero/anonymousHeroUpvote.svg?v=af2bb70d5d1b
200 https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/ru/Img/sprites.svg?v=f508971f422f
200 https://cdn.sstatic.net/img/hero/anonymousHeroBackground.svg?v=ac2b60532b92
200 https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/full-anon.ru.js?v=d3e2053c1fce
200 https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/explore-qlist.ru.js?v=5c7424c271ef
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Если интересны причины этого, можешь посмотреть дискуссию в [issue #141](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/141).

Comment: А откуда идут первые два запроса на https://accounts.google.com и https://www.gstatic.com? И почему? Я у себя вижу их тоже, но не пойму как отключить.

Comment: `accounts.google.com` - [GAIA root URL](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:google_apis/gaia/gaia_urls.cc;l=20), `gstatic` - это запрос в сервис перевода текста, ЕМНИП.

Comment: Спасибо. А нельзя ли их как-то отключить? Я не помню, чтобы я видел эти запросы раньше пока не стал использовать selenium-wire. Я их вижу даже если запрашиваю такую простую страницу как http://httpbin.org/ip

Comment: Эти запросы делаются браузером, а не `selenium-wire`. Отключить эти запросы можно только вырезав соотв. функционал из кода браузера и скомпилировав свою сборку хромиума.